# How I can perform write operation on cell of list view in wpf

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, silverlight, listview

I am developing wpf application using C# without using any framework.until now i successfully performed following task on list view .

- Displaying data in list view by binding with database table
- Getting the selected row data from list view based on primary key

Now I am searching on google for creating and Editing cells of list view and found many links on winform list view editing.The link that i found on google on wpf but it is using framework.

```
http://tech.pro/tutorial/857/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-3-in-place-edit
```

Here is my list view .

```
<ListView x:Name="lvitems" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="180" Margin="681,286,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="277">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="50"  Header="S\No" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=id}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="50"  Header="Code" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Code}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="70"  Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Description}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="Rate" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Rate}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="Empty" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Bottles}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Can some body tell me how to create and Edit the list view rows without using any framework ?Thanks

Comment: Use DataGrid instead. Place DataGridTemplateColumn instead of GridViewColumn. DataGridTemplateColumn allows customizing EditTemplate.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2008/09/15/editing-tabular-data-in-wpf-building-a-wpf-grid.aspx  From this link i am able to make my row of list view editable ......question is how add/ create new row in list view .and then how save those edited value